# What's the difference between binomial regression and logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution

I've always thought of logistic regression as simply a special case of binomial regression where the link function is the logistic function (instead of, say, a probit function).

From reading the [answers on another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13056/building-a-linear-model-for-a-ratio-vs-percentage) I had, though, it sounds like I might be confused, and there is a difference between logistic regression and binomial regression with a logistic link.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Logistic regression is a binomial regression with the "logistic" link function:

$$g(p)=\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)=X\beta$$

Although I also think logistic regression is usually applied to binomial proportions rather than binomial counts.

Comment: What do you mean by logistic regression being usually applied to proportions rather than counts? Suppose I'm trying to predict whether people will attend a party or not, and that for a particular party, I know that 9 people attended and 1 did not -- do you mean that logistic regression takes this as one training example (i.e., this party had a success rate of 0.9), while binomial regression with a link would take this as 10 training examples (9 successes, 1 failure)?

Comment: @raehtin - in both cases it would be $1$ sample/training case, with $(n_i,f_i)=(10,0.9)$ and $(n_i,x_i)=(10,9)$ respectively.  The difference is the form of the mean and variance functions.  For binomial, mean is $\mu_i=n_ip_i$, the canoncial link is now $\log\left(\frac{\mu_i}{n_i-\mu_i}\right)$ (also called the "natural parameter"), and the variance function is $V(\mu_i)=\frac{\mu_i(n_i-\mu_i)}{n_i}$ with dispersion parameter $\phi_i=1$.  For logistic we have mean $\mu_i=p_i$, the above link, variance function of $V(\mu_i)=\mu_i(1-\mu_i)$ and dispersion equal to $\phi_i=\frac{1}{n_i}$.

Comment: With logistic, the $n_i$ is separated out from the mean and variance functions, so can be more easily taken into account via weighting

Comment: Ah, got it, I *think* I see. Does this mean that they produce equivalent results (simply arrived at from a different way)?

Comment: @raegtin - I think so.  The GLM weights, $w_{i}^{2}=\frac{1}{\phi_i V(\mu_i)[g'(\mu_i)]^{2}}$, are equal in both cases, and the link function produces the same logit value.  So as long as the X variables are also the same, then it should give the same results.

Comment: @probabilityislogic Just for the sake of clarity, this is the logit link, not logistic. It becomes a logistic function when you solve for y, but then it shouldn't be called a "link" anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Binomial regression is any type of GLM using a binomial mean-variance relationship where the variance is given by $\mbox{var}(Y) = \hat{Y}(1-\hat{Y})$. In logistic regression the $\hat{Y} = \mbox{logit}^{-1}(\mathbf{X}\hat{\beta})=1/(1-\exp{(\mathbf{X}\hat{\beta})})$ with the logit function said to be a "link" function. However a general class of binomial regression models can be defined with any type of link function, even functions outputting a range outside of $[0,1]$. For instance, probit regression takes a link of the inverse normal CDF, relative risk regression takes as a link the log function, and additive risk models take the identity link model.