# Can term "logistic regression" be used pars pro toto for binomial regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, terminology

It is common to use the term "n-fold coin toss" for any type of Bernoulli experiment, although, strictly speaking, coin tossing is only a particular experiment and is the special case p=0.5. As a rhetorical figure, this usage is known as "pars pro toto", i.e., a special case is used for describing a much more general scenario.

Can the term "logistic regression" be used in the same way? It is the special case of binomial regression with the logit function as the "link function", but the term "binomial regression" is much less understood by practicioners than "logistic regression", and even the tags here on CV mention logistic regression, but not binomial regression. I thus wonder, whether it is preferable to use the term "logistic regression" in the title of a scientific paper and explain that it is meant *pars pro toto* in the text.

This question might be off-topic on CV, but I thought that the pundits to be asked might be found here.

PS: And NO, this thread does NOT answer my question: [What's the difference between binomial regression and logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13142/244807)

Comment: This is not common practice when using a probit link: I feel I've much more often heard people refer to that as "probit regression".

Comment: In general, introducing a "pars pro toto" in a field is not a good thing, per se. Doing this in title of a paper is fine, though. I assume you use it to be more relevant (somewhat marketing/rebranding your product). Since any statements made about binomial regression are also true about logistic regression, you are not "scamming" someone who only reads your paper for logistic regression. I would say this is common practice in academia.

Comment: Yes, it is about "marketing", or, more precisely, about being understood rather than being correct. Actually, the method presented in teh paper even applies to multinomial regression (and the paper explains how), but speaking of "multinomial regression" in the title will make sure that the paper will be read by noone.

Comment: Re your third paragraph: This is NOT off-topic here. We do have a tag for terminology!