# Regression using a percentage as an outcome?

Tags: regression, logistic, predictive-models

I am thinking about making a regression on these [data](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/clinton1.txt). 
As a dependent variable, I want to use percent of people in a county voting for Clinton in 1992. Is this appropriate?

I do not know if I should use linear or logistic regression. Can I even use logistic regression if my dependent variable is not categorical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logistic regression can use frequency weighting to model proportions as a number of yes/no votes. You should be able to get the county voting numbers and/or population from census information and merge them together. Even with weights, it's important to remember that this is still an ecological study.

Comment: What do you mean by an ecological study? Is linear regression totally inappropriate?

Comment: @Mrowkacala maybe you should do some self-directed research? A couple useful links https://www.nature.com/articles/6400454 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13056/building-a-linear-model-for-a-ratio-vs-percentage?rq=1